# Get contents of .txt file that is downloaded from url

Tags: javascript

I was messing around with some fetch requests that looks like this.

```
function translate(q) {
  var sourceText = q;
  var sourceLang = 'en';
  var targetLang = 'es';
  var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);
  var result = fetch(url);
  return result;
}
```

The problem is, this when visiting this URL, the result is a .txt file that is downloaded, contained JSON. Using Javascript, how can I extract the contents of this file and use the JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.  The fetch method returns a promise which needs to be resolved to get the data.  Using `.then` you can get the response from the fetch and then use the `.json()` method to extract the JSON from the server's response.

```js
function translate(q) {
  var sourceText = q;
  var sourceLang = 'en';
  var targetLang = 'es';
  var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);
  var result = fetch(url).then((resp) => {
    return resp.json();
  });
  return result; // As Promise
}

document.getElementById("fetch").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let promise = translate(document.getElementById("source").value);

  promise.then((json) => {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(json);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="source"></input>
  <button id="fetch">fetch</button>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Here's a good step-by-step blog about using fetch too: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

Comment: Thanks! I didn't quite understand before but this clears it up